# Programmatically add URL Patterns in Django?

Tags: python, django, django-admin, django-urls, django-settings

Is there a way to programmatically add URL Patterns to Django without having to restart the server?

Or is there a way force Django to reprocess/cache URL patterns ( the URLconf )?

Comment: Are you using `mod_wsgi`?  If so, you can restart your app without restarting the entire Apache server.

Comment: @S.Lott for the production server yes, so this might work, how do you restart a specific app? Is there anything similar for the dev server?

Comment: @S.Lott, For 'dev server' I mean the buit-in development server that comes with Django, eg: python manage.py runserver. I may have misunderstood your first comment though, were you suggesting it is possible to restart a single Django App without restarting the other Apps, or were you suggesting you can restart Django/All apps without having to restart Apache? I'd need to do the former.

Comment: The built-in development server that comes with Django restarts itself when you make a code change.  If you use `mod_wsgi`, the production server restarts itself when you touch the `wsgi` file.

Comment: @S.Lott, The changes are programmatic, so the source files do not change. I will read about wsgi and see if I can use it accomplish what I need.

Comment: "programmatic"?  What can that possibly mean?  The `urls.py` is read exactly once when Django starts up and cannot be re-read without restarting Django.

Comment: @S.Lott, programmatic, as in using python's type() to generate model classes, which is what I need the urls for. Classes that get generated using type() during the module import are working just fine, URLs and all, but if they are generated using the same functions post import, everything works as expected, except for URL handling.

Comment: This sounds like a you're doing too much of the wrong kind of metaprogramming.  Dynamic models and Dynamic URL's usurps Django as the framework.  Without considerably more details, I can only say that it sounds like you're using the tool incorrectly.  If you want to write your own framework, don't use an existing framework.

Comment: @S.Lott, haha I realize that without further context it may seem odd ( with context maybe only marginally better). I was testing an idea tangentially related to Django-Eav, http://mvpdev.github.com/django-eav/ .

Comment: If you're building dynamic models based on EAV, you've really wandered quite far afield.  Django gives you a great deal of flexibility.  EAV adds to that.  That's about the limit.  If you want more flexibility than that, I suggest you discard Django and EAV and begin again from the beginning with MongoDB and WerkZeug.

Comment: @S.Lott, Not to sound crass, but that suggestion isn't practical, relevant to what I am doing, or at this point related to the question I asked. As I said earlier what I am working on is **already functional** in all aspects except for the irritation of having to restart Django to get URLs added- which isn't needed too often, and will be less when things are solidified. So to, 'discard Django and EAV (not using it) and begin again from the beginning' would be a bad decision.

Comment: @instanceofTom: Not to sound any more crass than I already have, but what you're doing sounds -- again -- like you're doing too much of the wrong kind of metaprogramming.  The fact that elements work doesn't make it a good idea at all.

Comment: @S.Lott, I understand where you are coming from. However, this particular situation/app benefits from the metaprogramming, and there isn't a frightening quantity of it either. "The fact that elements work doesn't make it a good idea at all." Doesn't make it a bad idea either. What make an idea 'good' depends on the metrics you use to evaluate the it, in this case all of the metrics relevant to us (Performance and otherwise) are evaluating positively. http://code.djangoproject.com/wiki/AuditTrail shows an interesting application of the same type of meta-programming I am doing.

Comment: I don't know your intended usage, but if it's any help, you might want to check out [@kanu's answer to my question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20439825/2387772) about dynamic proxy models management in the admin site. There's a way to create dynamic sub-views for usage within the admin site, which sounds like that uber-functionality you are looking for. Maybe you should look at how the admin makes it happen and do something similar in your own project

Answer (score 4):

If you use gunicorn without code preloading, just send a HUP to the gunicorn master process, it will spawn new workers which load the new code, and gracefully shut down the old ones, without a single lost request!

Answer (score 3):

I tried something like this by hacking some things in `django.core.urlresolvers` – it worked for me but note that it's a **hack**. I don't still have the code, but I did something like this:

1. Django typically uses `urlresolvers.get_resolver()` to get a `RegexURLResolver` which is responsible for resolving URLs. Passing `None` to this function gets your "root" URLConf.
2. `get_resolver()` uses a cache, `_resolver_cache`, for loaded URLConfs.
3. Resetting `_resolver_cache` should force Django to recreate a clean URLResolver.

Alternatively, you might try to unset the `_urlconf_module` attribute of the root `RegexURLResolver`, which should force Django to reload it (not sure about this though, it's possible that the module will be cached by Python).

```
from urlresolvers import get_resolver

delattr(get_resolver(None), '_urlconf_module')
```

Again, not guaranteed that this will work (I'm working from memory from code that I've obviously discarded for some reason). But django/core/urlresolvers.py is definitely the file you'll want to look at.

**EDIT:** Decided to experiment some with this and it didn't work...

**EDIT2:**

As I thought, your URL modules will be cached by Python. Simply reloading them as they change might work (using `reload`). If, your problem is that you're dynamically constructing `urlpatterns` based on some data which might change.

I tried `reload`ing my root URLs (project.urls) and a suburl module (app.urls). That's all I had to do for the new URLs to be displayed by `get_resolver(None).url_patterns`

So the trick might be this simple: Manually reload your URL module.

Comment: When I get the chance I will play around with this and see if it works.

Comment: how do you `reload`? where this `reload` function is coming from? This is not clear

Answer (score 3):

Here is your answer :

```
import sys
from django.conf import settings
from importlib import reload
from django.urls import clear_url_caches

urlconf = settings.ROOT_URLCONF
  if urlconf in sys.modules:
      clear_url_caches()
      reload(sys.modules[urlconf])
```

Answer (score 1):

This seams also an elegant way to do it :

http://codeinthehole.com/writing/how-to-reload-djangos-url-config/

Simply do that to reload your root urls module :

```
reload_urlconf()
```